# AMPScript Issue - UpdateSingleSalesforceObject

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the below AMPScript but its not updating in SFDC -

```
%%[var @sflead, @Subskey 
set @sflead = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',%%_subscriberkey%%,'OptOut','true') 
]%%
```

It works when I hardcode the value of subscriber key but not without that. I have tried many other ways but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in AMPScript you do not add the "%%" to the personalization string call. That is only in raw HTML. ([ref](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_personalization_strings_with_ampscript/))

> Personalization strings that appear in AMPscript function calls cannot
>   include the surrounding percent symbols. For example, this code in
>   AMPscript is invalid:
>
> %%=UPPERCASE(%%emailaddr%%)=%%
>
> This format, however, is valid:
>
> %%=UPPERCASE(emailaddr)=%%

This should work:

```
%%[var @sflead, @Subskey 
set @sflead = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',_subscriberkey,'OptOut','true') 
]%%
```

Comment: I tried that again but didn't work. I am using this script in a Cloud Page. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Have you verified the subscriber key in SFMC matches the unique ID in SFDC? By default SFMC uses email address as subscriber key

Comment: I think there is something else wrong. What you suggested is correct. I tested it on  my emails. Somehow on Cloud Page, the personalization is not working.

Comment: oh I completely didnt see that.  Yes on cloud pages, you will need to use the MicrositeURL AMPScript (https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/sites/MicrositeURL.html) in order to pass attributes, etc of the subscriber to the landing page. Otherwise they will need to be passed via paramaters in the URL.